# Failing to create table using bound parameters in sqlalchemy/cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I want to execute a "create table" statement in-database using bound parameters. This works (without bound parameters):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

con = create_engine(\\..)
s = text("""create table test_table as select * from dual where 1 = 1 """)
con.execute(s)
```

However, if I use bound parameters:

```
s = text("""create table test_table as select * from dual where 1 = :a """)
con.execute(s, a = 1)
```

it fails with error `DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`.

I am not convinced this error has anything to do with the bound parameters because a simple select statement without table creation will work smoothly:

```
s = text("""select * from dual where 1 = :a """)
con.execute(s, a = 1).fetchall()
#[('X',)]
```

There seems to be something in the "create table" plus "bound parameters" that breaks the query. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind variables are not permitted in DDL statements. This is the reason why it works as expected with a simple query, but as soon as you have a create table statement, it fails. You will have to write your DDL statement without any bind variables, unfortunately!

Comment: That's a shame. Is there any underlying reason why this is not possible from a "developer" point of view ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Its been that way for a very long time so the reasons are probably shrouded in history! I plan to add a better error message to cx_Oracle, though.

Comment: FYI, I just pushed code to cx_Oracle that improves the error message when this takes place. It will be in 6.2 when that is released.